# Workflow won't generate a link to a document starting with 0. Why? How do I fix it?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

SharePoint 2010, SPD 2010

We have a document library and a list, and a workflow on each.  All the documents in the document library have the same naming convention of a 4-digit rep number.  However, some reps have 2- or 3-digit rep numbers, so 0s are added to the front of the file name to make it 4 digits.

When a document is uploaded, a workflow runs that does the following:

1. Set *Content Type ID* to *Link to a Document*
2. Set *Variable: Link* to *//serverurl[%Current Item:URL]*  (this contains the http: in the workflow, but I don't have enough rep to post 2+ links)
3. Set *Link* to *Variable: Link*

Then, in our list, an item is created and a workflow runs to do the following:

1. Set *Variable: Link* to *Link to Financial Plan*
2. Set *Link to Financial Plan* to *[%Variable: Link%]*

What I am finding is in the list, any item with a file name starting with anything other than 0 creates the link just fine, but anything with a file name beginning with 0 sets the text correctly, but not the link.

Here are screenshots I gathered from the DOM Explorer:

Starts with 0:

[image: Starts with 0:]

Starts with # > 0

[image: Starts with #>0]

Why would the workflow ignore one link but not the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that the rep numbers were not being entered consistently in both places.  In the library, they were entered with leading 0s, and the file names were named in the same manner.  However, in the list, leading 0s were being omitted.  Once leading 0s were added to the existing rep numbers and the workflow manually started again, the link generated correctly.